# How to return a comparison operator based on provided two values?

Tags: python

I would like to create a python function that once provided with two `int` values will return a comparison string. There are the obvious ways, of using `if` blocks or `for` and `while` loops. I am just curious to find out the best possible solution.

```
def get_comparison_operator(a, b):
    if a == b:
        op = '=='
    elif a > b:
        op = '>'
    # ... etc
    return op
```

A simple `if-else` block will run into the problem of distinguishing between `==` and `<=` or `>=` so probably I would go with a `for` loop with a `break`. However, as I said before, I am keen to learn the efficient way of doing this, if any.

Comment: You are doing pretty right as if-else is the only way. You can even do it with by using loops but it will make your code compact and inefficient. If-else is the simplest way for doing these type of comparisons.

Comment: Try harder, the logic of ```...distinguishing between == and <= or >=...``` should be easy to implement.

Comment: If you already show == and <, why would you have another case for <= at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `operator` module to reduce line count, but in the end of the day you need to keep list of operations to check.

```
import operator

operators = [operator.eq, operator.lt, operator.gt, operator.ne]
labels = ["==", "<", ">", "!="]

def get_comparison_operator(a, b):
    for op, label in zip(operators, labels):
        if op(a, b):
            return label
    return None
```

Obviously check order is crucial here, if greater equal is checked before greater, second one will not have a change to be returned.

Alternative form with list of tuples, I must say table-like form looks really nice.

```
import operator

operators = [
    (operator.eq, "=="), 
    (operator.lt, "<"),
    (operator.gt, ">"),
    (operator.ne, "!=")
]

def get_comparison_operator(a, b):
    for op, label in operators:
        if op(a, b):
            return label
    return None
```

Obviously, eq/lt/gt is fairly trivial, since 3 possibilities covers 100% of cases and they are mutually exclusive. Maybe for some weirder operators this approach makes more sense.

Comment: To make it clearer which label belongs to which operator I'd store them in one variable instead of two that are then zipped together, e.g. `operators = [(operator.eq, "=="), (operator.lt, "<"), ...]` but it's pretty moot.

Comment: Dict is a first choice for storing pairs, but it would guarantee an order. Of course, list of tuples is also a valid approach.

Comment: "since 3 possibilities covers 100% of cases" -- not quite 100%. If one or both operands are `float("nan")`, then only `!=` will return true.